# Write a custom join query in hive

Tags: sql, join, hive, union

I have two tables

```
table J:
P_ID  event   T_ID              URL
8187    6   14690481058450526   maplestage.com
8187    6   14690481058450527   maplestage.com

Table A:
P_ID  event   T_ID              URL
8187    7   14690481058450526   NULL
8187    7   14690481058450526   NULL
8187    7   14690481058450527   NULL
```

I have the following query to count the event that are 6 and events that are 7:

```
SELECT sum(if(j.event=6,1,0)) Type1, j.P_ID, j.URL, sum(if(a.event=7,1,0)) Type2  FROM Tabel_J j LEFT outer join Table_A a on a.T_ID = j.T_ID GROUP BY j.P_ID, j.URL;
```

The result i am getting is this:

```
Type1   P_ID          URL         Type2
3       8187      maplestage.com    3
```

The result i want to get is:

```
Type1   P_ID          URL         Type2
2       8187      maplestage.com    3
```

Please can someone help me with this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your data, the significance of the `T_ID` column isn't immediately obvious to me.  Having said that, based on what I think you are after (perhaps I'm wrong), this query might get you there:

```
SELECT
  SUM(IF(event=6,1,0)) Type1,
  P_ID,
  collect_set(URL)[0] URL,
  SUM(IF(event=7,1,0)) Type2
FROM
  (SELECT * FROM tabel_j UNION ALL SELECT * FROM table_a) everything
GROUP BY P_ID;
```

Comment: this worked thanks, also will this bale to work without Coalesce??

Comment: @user175084 That's a great point - I had thought the `coalesce` would be to filter out null values, but it appears that `collect_set` implicitly does this.  I'll edit the answer to remove `coalesce`.